# Find upper and lower bounds on the probability of the intersection $A\cap B\cap C$

Tags: probability

We let $(,,)$  be a probability space and we let $A, B$ and $C$ be be sets in $$, that fullfill that:

$$μ(A∩B) =μ(A∩C) =μ(B∩C) =\frac{2}{3}$$
and we have to show that:
$$1/2≤μ(A∩B∩C)≤\frac{2}{3}$$
Anyone who can help me with some hints to show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram of the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and all their possible intersections. We can label all distinct regions as below:

[image]

so that $z$ represents $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, $w$ represents $P(A\cap B\cap C^c)$, $x$ represents $P(B\cap C\cap A^c)$, and so on. (I'm using $P$ instead of $\mu$ for probability.)

Your goal is to find upper and lower bounds on $z$. To do that, write down what you know:
$w+z=\frac23$, $x+z=\frac23$, $y+z=\frac23$.
Summing these three equalities gives:
$$w+x+y+3z=2.\tag1$$
You also know that $w\ge0$, $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$. Combining this with (1) gives an upper bound on $z$: 
$$3z\le w+x+y+3z=2\tag2$$
from which we deduce $z\le\frac23$. 
For the lower bound on $z$, consider the fact that
$$
w+x+y+z\le1.\tag3$$
Can you combine this with (1) to obtain a lower bound on $z$?